# Asterisk symbol in Python

Tags: python, operators, operator-overloading

I was researching some different ways to approach the classic FizzBuzz problem, and stumbled across this:

```
for i in xrange(1, n+1):
    print "Fizz"*(i%3 == 0) + "Buzz"*(i%5 == 0) or i
```

Are the asterisks shorthand for an `if` statement?  If so, is this notation specific to `print`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @alecxe: operator-overloading was *not* an irrelevant tag; the reason this works in Python is exactly because of operator overloading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The asterisk in Python is actually just the standard multiplication operator `*`. It maps to the [`__mul__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mul__) method of the object it's operated on, and thus can be overloaded to have custom meanings. This has nothing to do whatsoever with `if` or `print`.

In the case of strings (`str` and `unicode`) it has been overloaded/overridden to mean repetition of strings such that `"foo" * 5` evaluates to `"foofoofoofoofoo"`.

```
>>> 'foo' * 5  # and the other way around 5 * "foo" also works
'foofoofoofoofoo'
```

and `"Fizz" * (i % 3 == 0)` is simply a "smart" shorthand for:

```
"Fizz" if i % 3 == 0 else ""
```

This is because the expression `i % 3 == 0` evaluates to a boolean, and booleans are a subtype of integers in Python, so that `True == 1` and `False == 0`, so that if you "multiply" a string with a boolean, you'll either get the same string out or the empty string.

**Note:** I would also like to note that in my experience/understanding, this type of programming style is not encouraged in Python—it makes the code less readable (to both newcomers as well as oldtimers) as well as not any faster (and in fact, likely, slower; see http://pastebin.com/Q92j8qga for a quick benchmark (but interestingly, not in PyPy: http://pastebin.com/sJtZ6uDm)).

---

And `*` also works on instances of `list` and `tuple`:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] * 3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

>>> (1, 2, 3) * 3
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

---

You can also define your own `*` operators for your types using what amounts to [operator overloading in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return "called %r with %r" % (self, other)

print Foo() * "hello"  # same as Foo().__mul__("hello")
```

outputs:

```
called <__main__.Foo object at 0x10426f090> with 'hello'
```

The case of `*` being mapped to `__mul__` also holds for "primitive" types such as `int`, `float` and others, so `3 * 4` is equivalent to `(3).__mul__(4)` (and same about other operators). In fact, you can even subclass `int` and provide a custom behavior for `*`:

```
class MyTrickyInt(int):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return int.__mul__(self, other) - 1
    def __add__(self, other):
        return int.__add__(self, other) * -1

print MyTrickInt(3) * 4  # prints 11
print MyTrickyInt(3) + 2  # prints -5
```

...but please don't do that :) (in fact, it doesn't hurt to stay clean of subclassing concrete types altogether!)

Comment: It's probably also necessary to point out that Boolean values (`True` and `False`) are also integers (`1` and `0`, respectively). So `"foo"*True` is `"foo"` while `"foo"*False` is an empty string.

Comment: I was adding that part when you mentioned this.

Answer (score 1):

asterik is for multiplication in python.If it works on string, it repeats the string to the specified number. For ex,

```
print "test"*0
print "test"*1
print "test"*2
```

Outputs:

```
<blank line>
test
testtest
```

In you case, you have `or` condition which evaluates from left to right:

```
print "Fizz"*(i%3 == 0) + "Buzz"*(i%5 == 0) or i
```

If `Fizz` or `Buzz` is Non zero/True, python will not even evaluate `i`

`Fizz` comes True when i is multiplication of 3 (so, it outputs 3 for all i values which can be divided by 3)
similarly, `Buzz` is true for all 5 multiplications.
`Fizz` and `Buzz` outputted when i could be divided by 15.
i is evaluated and printed when both of above condition is False.